# Should I only use canDisplayBannerAds. No ADBannerViews?

Tags: ios, iad

I want to implement iAds to my `UITabBar` application, and I discovered that if I use the `canDisplayBannerAds` property on each of my `ViewControllers` then the ads are displayed/hidden accordingly, resizing the view perfectly and it's so easy to implement (no `ADBannerView` added on Storyboard), but easy is almost never good.

Is there anything wrong with this? Do I need to add an `ADBannerView` either by code/storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to create an AdBannerView in code or the storyboard. I'm using canDisplayBannerAds in my apps and it is working fine. Apple does everything for you and you mustn't take care about memory leaks, rendering issues, error handling, ...

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anything wrong with this?

No, `canDisplayBannerAds` is easy to implement and requires no effort to manage. I usually suggest using `canDisplayBannerAds` when someone is placing advertisements into their application for the first time. It gets them familiar with advertisements and iAd.

> Do I need to add an `ADBannerView` either by code/storyboard?

No, using `canDisplayBannerAds` does not require you to implement an `ADBannerView`. The moment you *need* an `ADBannerView` you'll know it. For example, you want to use another ad network for when iAd fails to receive an ad. Using `canDisplayBannerAds` you're not able to do this. You need the delegate methods you would inheret from using your own `ADBannerView`.